# Is there a closed-form solution to this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, quadratic-forms

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be an $n$-dimensional real vector (unknown).

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an $n \times n$ real matrix  (possibly non-symmetric).

Let $\mathbf{b}$ be an $n$-dimensional real vector (known).

Consider the following equation

$\mathbf{b}\;=\;\mathrm{diag}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$

where $\mathrm{diag}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\;=\;\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
x_{1} & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & x_{2} & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & x_{n}
\end{array}\right]$

Is there a good soul out there that can:

1) Tell me whether there is a closed-form ($\mathbf{x}$) solution to the equation above?

2) If yes, which one is it. If no, how can I find $\mathbf{x}$ numerically (say, in MATLAB). $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ are real data objects and $n \approx 5000$

Comment: Amended the question to clarify what I mean by $\mathrm{diag} (\mathbf{x} )$

Comment: Does this equation come from a model of a physical system, such that the $(A,b)$ parameters ensure that a solution vector exists? Or do you have some other reason to believe that a real solution vector exists?

Comment: This equation does come from a physical system, but I do not have a sense of whether the observed $\mathbf{A}$ and  $\mathbf{b}$ ensure the existence of a real solution.

Comment: Even in 1D this is $b=ax^2$, so if $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs there is no real solution. If the signs are the same there are two, and the number goes up with dimension. If $A$ is symmetric this can be reduced to solving the algebraic Riccati equation of a special form, $\mathrm{diag}(x)A\,\mathrm{diag}(x)=B$, for a $B$ such that $b=B\,(1,1,...,1)^T$. There are plenty of standard methods for doing that, but again, there are multiple solutions when they exist at all.

Comment: Newton-Raphson iteration yields a numerical solution (depending on the initial $x$ value)
$${
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\D#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
x
 \:=\: x \;-\; \BR{\D{Ax}+\D{x}A\,}^{-{\tt1}}\,\BR{\D{x}Ax-b\,}  \\
}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closed-form?  I don't think so.  I tried a $3 \times 3$ case with random $A$ and $b$.  Your equation became three quadratics in $x_1, x_2, x_3$:
$$\eqalign{ 85\,{x_{{1}}}^{2}+27\,x_{{2}}x_{{1}}+45\,x_{{1}}x_{{3}}-3 &= 0\cr85\,x_{{2}}
x_{{1}}+96\,{x_{{2}}}^{2}+89\,x_{{2}}x_{{3}}+5 &=0\cr-48\,x_{{1}}x_{{3}}+76
\,x_{{2}}x_{{3}}-44\,{x_{{3}}}^{2}-11 &= 0}$$

Solving with
Groebner basis methods, $x_3$ must satisfy a rather awful polynomial (irreducible over the rationals) of degree $8$: 
$$ 85991383888960\,{x_{{3}}}^{8}+119524075710384\,{x_{{3}}}^{6}+
45323805092604\,{x_{{3}}}^{4}+4288390645605\,{x_{{3}}}^{2}+
175173708600 = 0
$$
By the way, this has no real roots.

Extrapolating, I wouldn't be surprised if for $n=5000$ the polynomial had degree $2^{5000}$.  So there's no way you can find an exact solution (even if you count algebraic numbers as in principle "closed form").
Numerical methods are the only realistic option.  And, as this example also shows, don't expect there to always be a real solution.

Comment: Apologies! I had forgotten to accept your answer. Your answer was excellent. You totally convinced me that a closed form solution was not feasible - I was thus able to focus  on finding a numerical solution, which I did soon after. Thank you!